# Use previous calculated row value in r Continued

Tags: r, data.table, lag

I have a data.table that looks like this:

```
DT <- data.table(A=1:20, B=1:20*10, C=1:20*100)
DT
    A  B   C
1:  1  10  100
2:  2  20  200
3:  3  30  300
4:  4  40  400
5:  5  50  500
...
20: 20 200 2000
```

I want to be able to calculate a new column "G" that has the first value as the average of the first 20 rows in column B as the first value, and then I want to use the first row of column G to help calculate the next row value of G.

Say the Average of the first 20 rows of column B is 105, and the formula for the next row in G is: DT$G[2] = DT$G[1]*2, and the next row again is DT$G[3]=DT$G[2]*2. This means that the first value should not be used again in the next row and so forth.

```
    A    B   C       G
1:  1   10   100     105
2:  2   20   200     210
3:  3   30   300     420
4:  4   40   400     840
5:  5   50   500     1680
...
20: 20  200  2000    55050240
```

Any ideas on this would be made?

Comment: what are your ideas?

Comment: `DT[, G := mean(B[1:20]) * 2^(0:19)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a little arithmetic:

```
DT$G <- mean(DT$B[1:20])
DT$G <- DT$G * cumprod(rep(2,nrow(DT)))/2
```

Or using `data.table` syntax, courtesy of @DavidArenburg:

```
DT[ , G := mean(B[1:20]) * cumprod(rep(2, .N)) / 2]
```

or from @Frank

```
DT$G <- cumprod(c( mean(head(DT$B,20)), rep(2,nrow(DT)-1) ))
```

Comment: For the (future) readers, please use `:=` syntax, as `<-` results in losing *over-allocation* of column pointers (which'd result in a warning the next time you use `:=` about having to shallow copy).

Comment: I see that it fulfills my solution, but the way it does it is not the way I want it to. 
You create a vector of "2", take the cumulative product of 2, divde by 2, and then multiply by the mean.

But I would like to have way to directly use the previous row, and not like this. But thanks for the effort by the way

Comment: @KhalidN Calculate a value per row and then looking back and then recalculate again will be highly inefficient and slow. This solution is fully vectorized and my guess that this is as best at it can get.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes I can understand that it is a bit slower setup, but for more complex problems like mine, I need to have the solution like this. My real problem is a much more complex formula then stated above. My real formula is like this for the first row: DT$R[1]<-tanh(DT$B[1]/400000), for the second row the formula is: DT$R[2] <- 0.5*tanh(DT$B[2]/400000) + DT$R[1]*0.6, and row three DT$R[3] <- 0.5*tanh(DT$B[3]/400000) + DT$R[2]*0.6. So as you can see, it should be resolved like this, even though the vector solution is great in the different case

Answer (score 0):

```
mycalc <- function(x, n) {
  y <- numeric(n)
  y[1] <- mean(x)
  for (i in 2:n) y[i] <- 2*y[i-1]
  y
}
DT[ , G := mycalc(B[1:20], .N)]
```